# Does anyone have any suggestions for a Selenium with Ruby tutorials?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2

I have gone through this book http://www.compendiumdev.co.uk/selenium/ which is excellent and I highly recommend it to everyone! I was wondering if there is a similar book/tutorial with a Ruby focus that anyone would recommend?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for Selenium + Ruby or just want to learn more Ruby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](http://anahorny.blogspot.com/2011/08/selenium-webdriver-ruby-tutorial.html) the sort of thing you are looking for ?

Comment: This is definitely what they're looking for.  I have yet to find a better intro/tutorial to writing to Webdriver/SE with Ruby.  Great recommendation.

Comment: How about giving my answer an uovote then ? :)

Comment: Done, just commented in a hurry :)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Cucumber & Cheese](https://leanpub.com/cucumber_and_cheese) (A Testers Workshop) by Jeff Morgan.

Comment: I probably will as well once I've finished reading it !

Comment: This appears to be Water focused, am I wrong about this?

Comment: It is, but the lessons learned in it will be v useful to you

Comment: @moorecats: watir-webdriver Ruby gem is just an API over selenium-webdriver Ruby gem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Selenium Design Patterns and Best Practices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1783982705). Great book for learning Selenium and Ruby, and what is even more important for learning best test automation practices along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few years old but I wanted to bring up another option.

My company bought a copy of the ruby version of [The Selenium GuideBook](https://seleniumguidebook.com/) by Dave Haeffner, who also does the [Elemental Selenium Tips](http://elementalselenium.com/tips) newsletter. The book costs about $60 but is very much worth it. I've gone through the book a few times, using the code examples and I love it. Got me up and running using Selenium WebDriver using Ruby and RSpec doing automated acceptance tests.